# TinyMCE is stripping out HTML comments

Tags: tinymce

When I input html comments in TinyMCE's html editor, TinyMCE strips out the comment tag. How do prevent TinyMCE from stripping out HTML comments?

Comment: This will depend on what your configuration is and also possibly the version you are using. If you try the Full Feature demo (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) you can add a HTML comment successfully in IE, Safari and Firefox. You perhaps have set your valid_elements. Alternatively, have you checked that it's TinyMCE stripping it and not your backend.